# Question lists empty

Tags: bug, status-norepro, question-lists

I hope someone can see this post because the same thing happens in the `bugs` tab on meta for me right now:

[image]

---

**Edit:**

[Bug list on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/?tab=bugs) works now.

[Go tag listing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/go) still broken (as in screenshot).

---

**Edit:**

Go tag listing now working again.

Comment: Works fine for me. Just refresh one or two times.