# Question list not loaded

Tags: bug, status-norepro, question-lists

What happened here?

[image: screenshot of Skeptics.SE]

This is the relevant HTML (via Inspector):

```
<div id="qlist-wrapper">
    <div id="question-mini-list">

    </div>
</div>
```

Reloading the page (which is the main page of Skeptics, incidentally) fixes the problem – so it’s not very serious … just puzzling.

Comment: The URL meight be helpful.

Comment: @rekire “which is the main page of Skeptics, incidentally”

Comment: Possibly related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200493/question-lists-empty

Comment: Two independent bug reports. [meta-tag:status-norepro] seems hardly accurate.